# Sum of the same powers of different real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Find the number of pairs $(a_1,a_2,...a_6)$ satisfying

$$a^2_1 +a^2_2 +···+a^2_6 =6$$

and

$$(a_1 +a_2 +···+a_6)(a^3_1 +a^3_2 +···+a^3_6)=36.$$

Work:

I squared the first equation and subtracted the second from it to get $2(a_1^2a_2^2 + a_1^2a_3^2 + \dots +a_5^2a_6^2) = a_1(a_2^3+a_3^3+...a_6^3) + a_3(a_1^3+a_3^3+ \dots + a_6^3) +\dots + a_6(a_1^3+a_2^3+ \dots + a_5^3).$

Problem: I am completely stuck from here.

Comment: Should that be integers or even natural numbers? If so, please complete.

Comment: Please write the assumptions from the title also clearly in the text.

Comment: @mathmule, I noticed that none of your questions has accepted answers. If an answer answers your question, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark right below the downvote button.

Comment: May the person voting to close this question explain why? What did this problem not satisfy?

Comment: everyone thank you for the help, I am a new user so I just figured out how to accept answers sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution assumes that we're dealing with non-negative numbers.

By Cauchy-Schwarz, $$a_1^2+\dots+a_6^2=a_1^{\frac 1 2}a_1^{\frac 3 2}+\dots+a_6^{\frac 1 2}a_6^{\frac 3 2}\leq \sqrt{\left(a_1+\dots+a_6\right)\left( a_1^3+\dots+a_6^3\right)}$$
Here both the left-hand side and right-hand side are equal to 6.

Thus this is the equality case of Cauchy-Schwarz, which implies that there is $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$\forall i=1\dots 6,\,\,\,\,\,\,a_i^{\frac 1 2}=\lambda a_i^{\frac 3 2}$$
This implies that $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_6$.

This implies that $a_1=\dots=a_6=1$

Comment: You forgot $a_1=\dots=a_6=-1$

Comment: And the OP said "different real numbers" in the title, so there is no solution anyway (we can stop at $a_1=a_2=\cdots$).

Comment: Thanks @IraeVid. I modified the answer to restrict to non-negative numbers. I'm unclear as to whether OP intended any restrictions on the numbers.

Comment: There's also the non-negative solution any one variable is $\sqrt6$, the rest all are $0$, if the numbers need not be distinct.  Also any two numbers being $\sqrt3$ and all the rest zero and so on...

Answer (score 4):

We claim that there are no solutions. Suppose otherwise, that there is a solution. By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have

$$
36=(a_1 +a_2 +···+a_6)(a^3_1 +a^3_2 +···+a^3_6)\geq(a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_6^2)^2=36
$$

Hence, equality for the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality must be achieved. This means that $a_i^3/a_i=a_i^2$ must be constant, or that $|a_i|$ must be constant. Suppose that $|a_i|=x$. Then, $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_6$ must be either $x$ or $-x$. By the Pigeonhole Principle, there must be $3$ of $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_6$ that is equal. However, the condition requires $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_6$ to be distinct, and we have a contradiction. Hence, there are no solutions.

Comment: Your use of CS inequality assumes $a_i$ are all non-negative... So actually this doesn't prove there are no real solutions, just that they can't be all positive. For instance, the problem $x^2+y^2=2, (x+y)(x^3+y^3)=4$ has a solution $(x, y) = (0, \pm \sqrt2)$, while above logic would say there are no solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Macavity, but doesn't CS Inequality hold true even for negative numbers?

Comment: It does, but that's not the issue. You're not applying the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to vectors with negative components. You're applying the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to vectors $(\sqrt{a_1}, \sqrt{a_2}, \sqrt{a_3}, \sqrt{a_4}, \sqrt{a_5}, \sqrt{a_6})$ and $(\sqrt{a_1^3}, \sqrt{a_2^3}, \sqrt{a_3^3}, \sqrt{a_4^3}, \sqrt{a_5^3}, \sqrt{a_6^3})$, and you can't take those square roots if any $a_i$ is negative.